# What is the difference between using a win32 function and passing a cmd command through system()?

Tags: c++, winapi

should i use win32 functions if a terminal command can do the same thing through `system();`? Like, what is the difference between using a win32 function to, for example, create a file and using `system("echo  >> file.txt");`.

Comment: Choose the more direct route. Call a function rather than create a process to call the same function.

Comment: How do you think the command you call through `system` is going to accomplish the task?

Comment: I must ask - what would be a correct answer to this question?

Answer (score 4):

> should i use win32 functions if a terminal command can do the same thing through `system();`?

This asks for opinions, but I'm going out on a limb and say: Almost never use `system()`.

One category of reasons to actually use it is if you need to use a program that doesn't come with a library/API - but it has an understandable commandline interface. I place all usage of `system()` in the *as a last resort* bin. It's nearly never what you should aim for.

> Like, what is the difference between using a win32 function to, for example, create a file and using `system("echo  >> file.txt");`.

The `system()` call on Windows and Posix platforms creates a child process (`cmd.exe`, `/bin/sh` or whatever shell is the default) to execute the command. The main process then just waits for the child process to finish.

This sub shell has to interpret the command, validate it and print all sorts of meaningless messages to `stdout` when you as a programmer are usually interested in if creating the file succeeded or not. All this usually takes a lot more system resources than just calling the API at hand.

The shells are also different beasts and come in different versions so your program may behave differently if deployed on different versions of your target platform. This isn't detected at program startup as it would be if your program linked with the proper libraries instead. Different shells have different security vulnerabilities and programs using `system()` have historically been successfully attacked. Since you probably don't know the version of the shell you use, you also have no control over this part.

That said, I don't recommend calling the WinAPI directly to accomplish what your example does. Using standard C++ should do quite well:

```
if(std::ofstream os("file.txt", std::ios::app); os) {   // c++17 init-statement
    os << '\n';
} else {
    // failed opening "file.txt" for writing
}
```

Edit: [dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538420/dxiv) pointed out that my suggestion doesn't do what `echo  >> file.txt` does when using `cmd.exe` as a shell. This would apparently be the equivalent:

```
    os << "ECHO is on.\n";
```

As also pointed out by *dxiv*, this "*reinforces both* "may behave differently" *and* "print all sorts of meaningless messages".

Comment: `os << '\n';` Technically, the equivalent of OP's `echo  >> file.txt` is `os << "ECHO is on.\n";`, which reinforces both "*may behave differently*" and "*print all sorts of meaningless messages*" points ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`system()` creates a new instance of the command interpreter (`cmd.exe`) and runs the specified command in it.  There's a substantial overhead to creating a new process, so you should only do so if you absolutely need to.  This is a dumb analogy, but it would be like saying, hmm, I need a refrigerator, I'll build a whole house so I can use the fridge.

Furthermore, you'll find that if you use `system()`, the created process's `stdin` and `stdout` are not accessible to your program without further work.  So you can't tell much about what it did other than by reading the return code.

Compare that to calling Windows API functions to accomplish your task, which are much faster since they don't have the process creation overhead, provide rich error codes, and on top of that also provide *tons and tons* more functionality than does `cmd.exe`.